# Where are my custom Dota 2 item builds saved?

Tags: dota-2

I did a custom build for Pudge and I want to backup it so i can try out this custom build manager :`D2RIC_1.3.3`

I only found the default ones in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\itembuilds` and its subfolder.

So does anyone know the exact path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently it is stored in the steamcloud

`\Steam\userdata\XXX\570\remote\itembuilds`

570 is the DotA2 gameid

Answer (score -2):

Open Shop Menu, click the pencil on the top left of your recommended items and start dragging the items you usually use on your build on to your recommended items and if desired delete the initial recommended items.

Comment: Welcome to the site! My question was directed towards the files that get created via the ingame builder (that you described). So your answer does not help in this context. Sorry