# Is there a way to copy a hero build in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

One thing I often do in Dota is set up custom item builds, so that when I'm playing a hero all the items I like to buy as that hero are in the suggested items section of the shop, for quick, convenient access.

Often, when setting up these builds I like to start with the default build or a build on the steam workshop and tweak that a bit to suit my style. Unfortunately, when creating builds it looks like you have to start from scratch. Is that true, or is there some way that I'm not aware of to copy an existing build and then edit that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can modify a preexisting build.

Just open the build (book from left upper corner) and then open the store.

After this you can click the little icon i marked which will make the itembuild editable.

Feel free to adjust to your needs!

I tested it with someone else's too even if the picture shows editing my own.

[image]

Comment: can you save it localy then ?

Comment: afaik it gets saved into your steamcloud and then it should be located here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64614/where-are-my-custom-dota-2-item-builds-saved/64748#64748

Comment: Awesome? So I have to be in-game to do this, right? (Or in a bot match?)

Comment: yes afaik ingame. i created this screenshot in my own lobby game without bots or players